# Is the set $\frac {x^2 /(1+x^2)} x$ connected in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: analysis

The set lies in the interval $[0,1)$ with points in $\mathbb Q$ so it becomes a subset of $\mathbb Q$, the former being not connected and so the set also becomes disconnected?

Comment: Connectedness is for sets. You are asking if a function is connected.

Comment: Is $x$ a positive integer? Are you asking if the range of the function is connected?

Comment: *Very* confusing. Edit.

Comment: $\frac {x^2 /(1+x^2)} x$ is a formula, not a set. Before we can answer your question, you need to explain exactly what set you are talking about.